# Need help identifying a font often used in the figures of scientific papers

Tags: fonts, font-identification

In the figures of scientific papers, I have been seeing this font very often (image below). I see this font in papers as old as from 2010s. I like the simplicity of this font and would like to use it. However, the issue is that I don't know the name of this font.

This 'sans' font has characteristic capital 'C' (no inward curves) , 'M' (angled outer lines) and lower 'c' (no inward curves), 'l' (just a straight line) letters.

To search this font based on a scientific figure I had, I used image-based search engines e.g. the one of Adobe and others.

The closest fonts I found were following two, but after looking closely, I realized that they are not the right ones, because of some subtle differences.

1. Trebuchet MS, but lower 'c' and 'l' are different.
2. Myriad, but 'f' and 'i' should not be connected in 'fi' i.e. if lower 'f' and 'i' are adjacent, there should not be connection between them. The upper dot of 'i' in 'fi' should be visible.

I wonder if I could get any help in this regards. I think getting an expert's opinion here is my last option in this investigation.

Here's some extra information that may probably help.
I am a python coder myself and I use linux and I never encountered this font while making scientific figures. So probably this font is used by plotting software of another coding language or OS or just a graphic maker (e.g. Adobe illustrator).

[image]

Comment: You can use this useful tool to identify a font from an image: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is some kind of **Myriad**.

See here how neatly Myriad Pro Regular fits on top of your screenshot:

[image]

(Ligatures like *fi* can be turned off in your layout application.)

Comment: Yes, it's Myriad. Bundled with Adobe Indesign, which is the main layout software used for professional publications. What you're describing with 'fi' is a ligature, which may or may not be enabled depending on layout settings. Tip: in Adobe Acrobat and Acrobat Reader, going to document information lists all fonts embedded inside a pdf file.